# Joining a subquery using an outer column that uses a group function

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, subquery

So this one should be pretty simple for most of you:

My table has an ID, an order_id and a status.
The same order_id may have several IDs.

What I need to do is get the last ID from each order_id, which is pretty simple:

```
SELECT order_id, max(ID) AS last_id 
FROM mytable
GROUP BY order_id
```

Now, I also need to get the status that is linked to last ID, so what I was trying to do was:

```
SELECT order_id, max(ID) AS last_id, x.status
FROM mytable t

LEFT JOIN (SELECT ID, status
          FROM mytable) x ON last_id = x.ID
```

I know I'm not allowed to use the last_id alias to join the subquery, as it says it does not exist. So how do I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the alias in the `FROM` or in the `WHERE` parts of the query, you should use `max(t.ID)`:

```
SELECT order_id, max(t.ID) AS last_id, x.status
FROM mytable t

LEFT JOIN (SELECT ID, status
          FROM mytable) x ON MAX(t.ID) = x.ID
```

You can also wrap the query as a subquery and then do the join using the alias:

```
SELECT t.order_id, t.last_id, x.status
FROM (
  SELECT order_id, max(ID) AS last_id
  FROM mytable
) t
LEFT JOIN mytable x
ON t.last_id = x.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to `DISTINCT ON` the column `order_id` and then apply `max()` on `id`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (order_id) 
  order_id, max(id) AS last_id,
  status
FROM mytable 
GROUP BY order_id,status;
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=4dd28bae1fb3384f5e4be2590d5b0a49)